# Error al importar un módulo de python

Tags: python, idle

Soy nuevo en el ecosistema de Python. Intento importar un módulo ejecutando las siguientes acciones en python IDLE con la versión de python 2.7.3

```
   import sys

   sys.path.append("/Users/apl00.DESKTOP-IGEQ9D2/Desktop/CloudStation/Proyectos/Curso de python/Tema 3/")

   import dvd.py
```

y obtengo el siguiente error

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
        import dvd.py
        File "/Users/apl00.DESKTOP-IGEQ9D2/Desktop/CloudStation/Proyectos/Curso de python/Tema 3/dvd.py", line 4, in <module>
        import add_dvd
        File "/Users/apl00.DESKTOP-IGEQ9D2/Desktop/CloudStation/Proyectos/Curso de python/Tema 3/add_dvd.py", line 3, in <module>
        import MySQLdb, random, os
        ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

¿Alguien podría decirme donde está mi fallo y alguna manera más rápida de ejecutar el módulo sin tener que estar al principio dando la ruta donde lo tengo ubicado?

Comment: Parece que estás usando Python 3x, a partir de esta versión, la sentencia `print` 
 pasó a ser una función y debes usarla como `print("cadena que quieres imprimir")`

Comment: Sigue la recomendación de Patricio. Todo indica que es un archivo hecho para Python 2 y estás ejecutándolo con Python3. Para que funcione, TODOS los usos de print deben cambiarse para que invoque la función correctamente. Revisa en los métodos de los otros archivos `.py` que usa el switch, que es donde deben estar los mensajes.

Comment: Aparte de `print` tendrás que cambiar más cosas para portar el codigo a Python 3, por ejemplo `raw_input` debes cambiarlo por `input` y `xrange` por `range`, son dos de los más comunes. `xrange` no se si lo usa algún módulo en tu caso, pero `raw_input` por lo pronto si, el propio `dvd.py`

Comment: He modificado la pregunta del post ahora con la versión de python 2.7.3

Comment: Sorprendentemente (por el ".py") el modulo dvd lo intenta cargar, el error dice que te falta el módulo MySQLdb (pip install mysqlclient), requerido por add_dvd.

Comment: MySQLdb es un paquete de terceros, no pertenece a la biblioteca estándar. Debes instalarlo por tanto vía PIP:  https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/

Comment: He instalado MySQL-python en mi ordenador usando ubuntu he ejecutado esto pip install MySQL-python. Ubuntu me da un mensaje de que se ha instalado correctamente. No obstante cuando intento ejecutar import dvd.py me sale el mismo error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    import MySQLdb ImportError: No module named MySQLdb Disculpen por mi ignorancia en el entorno de python, me gustaría saber como ejecutarlo. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Además de hacerlo con la terminal de ubuntu me he aventurado a hacerlo como explica en este artículo https://pynative.com/install-mysql-connector-python/ descargando la versión en zip y ejecutandolo con cmd. Posteriormente pude ver como se instaló correctamente el paquete en el directorio de C. Por otro lado sigo obteniendo el mismo error cuando ejecuto import dvd.py